# Show error message : "fill_alpha" can't find

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmosaic

When run the code, below error message popped. Anyone can help ?

Error Message:

```
Error in fill_alpha(data$fill %||% "grey20", data$alpha) : 
  could not find function "fill_alpha"
```

The code :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmosaic)

ggplot(data = titanic) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(Class), fill= Survived)) +
  geom_mosaic_text(size=5,aes(x = product(Class), fill = Survived))
```

Comment: I can reproduce your error using `ggplot2 3.4.4`. But it works fine using `ggplot2 3.5.0`, i.e. try with updating `ggplot2`.

Comment: It's a new feature, see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html#new-features-3-5-0

Comment: Thanks , after updating the packages , the code run correct . Thanks!